# beautiful soup div data parsing errors

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Sample code:

```
<div class="sort-line selected"  
data-discount="3392" 
data-count="669" 
data-ship_price="0"
>
```

I want parse "669" by bs4 but have error 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to isolate the tag, then you can treat it like a dictionary to get the required attribute value. [Read the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) for more regarding this.

```
html="""
<div class="sort-line selected"
data-discount="3392"
data-count="669"
data-ship_price="0">
</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
div=soup.find('div')
print(div['data-count'])
```

Output:

```
669
```

If there are many divs you should include more [filters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters) to isolate the div.
Eg.

```
div=soup.find('div',class_="sort-line selected")
```

With your url

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://pandao.ru/product/b89db09a-d978-437c-be37-a0c2ceffc315?d=1de543b5-527e-44e4-9888-d880d1a3c331&pid=7a9bf860-bcc7-41ea-a03f-c6bcd3e2b8f5')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
div=soup.find('div',class_="sort-line selected")
print(div['data-count'])
```

Output:

```
667
```

Comment: KeyError: 'data-count'

Comment: @ВАСЯВОРОН I am able to get an output.Maybe you could share the full url or the code that you are trying? It is most likely an issue of not applying enough filters.

Comment: view-source:https://pandao.ru/product/b89db09a-d978-437c-be37-a0c2ceffc315?d=1de543b5-527e-44e4-9888-d880d1a3c331&pid=7a9bf860-bcc7-41ea-a03f-c6bcd3e2b8f5

Comment: @ВАСЯВОРОН see the edit. use the class filter also like div=soup.find('div',class_="sort-line selected")